# Device not compatible with this application

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I need a help. I am having a application which does not show compatibility issue when i am using it on various devices like nexus 4, samsung s3 but show device not compatible on devices having same android version phones like nexus 5 samsung s4 how can i resolve please help? I have to put many permissions in manifest Because used in checking if that is the issue please tell me how to resolve.

Comment: Are you using camera permission in your app? can you post your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html There you can find a tool to check how google play will filter the devices that are compatible with your app ("section Google Play and Feature-Based Filtering"), and if you read a bit further you can find more information about how to resolve them.